# Changing the default wp_search_stopwords

Tags: wp-query, filters

I want to change the default stopwords in the wordpress search. I'm sure it's easy but I can't figure it out.

Per this https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_search_stopwords/ the default stopwords are:

```
$words = explode( ',', _x( 'about,an,are,as,at,be,by,com,for,from,how,in,is,it,of,on,or,that,the,this,to,was,what,when,where,who,will,with,www',
        'Comma-separated list of search stopwords in your language' ) );
```

So, I would think I could just add_filter it in like this:

```
add_filter( 'wp_search_stopwords', array('meh') );
```

But `meh` is still being applied to the search results.

I found this https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/25587 which has the following at the end, but I don't know what to do in the `do whatever you want` part:

```
function a_whatever() {
    remove_filter( 'wp_search_stopwords', __FUNCTION__ );
    // do whatever you want
}
add_filter( 'wp_search_stopwords', 'a_whatever' );
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close: you indeed need to define a filter, but you've not quite gotten the filter definition right:

```
function add_meh_stopword($stopwords) {
    $stopwords[] = 'meh'; // *add* "meh" to the list of stopwords
    // if instead you want to completely replace the list of stopwords
    // use $stopwords = array('meh');
    return $stopwords;
}
add_filter( 'wp_search_stopwords', 'add_meh_stopword');
```

The second argument to the `add_filter` function takes a "callable", i.e. in this case a function name. That function then returns the modified list of stopwords.

Hope this helps!

Comment: At first this didn't seem to work, but it does on a fresh install with no plugins so now I have to do the dreaded plugin/theme conflict hunt. Thanks for getting me to comprehend how to properly add_filter!